# not able to move multiple images to another folder at a time

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-asynctask

I wrote some code for moving multiple images from one folder to another using an image gallery app I created. I am able to select multiple images but only one image is moved at a time.
Multiple images get selected to the arraylist but **the for loop for moving images runs only once.**
The for loop for multiple selection is running properly and it returns the correct number of images being selected.
There is something wrong with the for loop running inside Asynctask.I am not able to figure out why it runs only once. It runs in `doinBackground()` of AsyncTask on `ImagesGallery.java` 
How do I fix that ?

**PhotosActivity.java**:

```
 private ArrayList<Integer> mSelected = new ArrayList<>();

 gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                if (mSelected.contains(position)) {
                    mSelected.remove(position);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);// remove item from list
                    // update view (v) state here
                    // eg: remove highlight
                } else {
                    mSelected.add(position);
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);// add item to list
                    // update view (v) state here
                    // eg: add highlight
                }

   buttoncut.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                buttoncut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Intent moveIntent = new Intent(PhotosActivity.this, ImageGallery.class);
                                moveIntent.putExtra("selected_images", getImagePaths(mSelected));
                                moveIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                startActivity(moveIntent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

  private ArrayList<String> getImagePaths(ArrayList<Integer> selectedIndexList) {
        ArrayList<String> listOfImages = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Integer index : selectedIndexList) {
            listOfImages.add(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(index));  //images get added to arraylist here
        }
        return listOfImages;
    }
```

**ImageGallery.java**:

```
 ArrayList<String> selectedImages = new ArrayList<>();

 if (getIntent().getSerializableExtra("selected_images") != null)
            selectedImages = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("selected_images");

   gv_folder.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
                for (int j = 0; j < adapterView.getChildCount(); j++)
                    adapterView.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                // change the background color of the selected element
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                buttoncut.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button2.setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                buttoncut.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                buttonpaste.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                new LongOperation(i).execute();
                            }

                        });

 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, File> {

  @Override
        protected File doInBackground(String... params) {

         for (String imagePath : selectedImages) {   //this is the second for loop which might be running only once  
                File sourceImage = new File(imagePath); //returns the image File from model class to
                // be// moved.

                File destinationImage = new File(al_images.get(id).getDirectoryPath() +
                        File.separator + sourceImage.getName());

                try {
                    moveFile(sourceImage, destinationImage, false);
                    return destinationImage;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }



 private void moveFile(File file_Source, File file_Destination, boolean isCopy) throws IOException {
        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        if (!file_Destination.exists()) {
            file_Destination.createNewFile();
        }

        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(file_Source).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(file_Destination).getChannel();

            long count = 0;
            long size = source.size();
            while ((count += destination.transferFrom(source, count, size - count)) < size) ;
            if (!isCopy) {
                file_Source.delete();
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                        new String[] { file_Source.toString() }, null,
                        new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                                Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                            }
                        });
            }
        } finally {
            if (source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if (destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the size of  `listOfImages` after selecting multiple image?

Comment: its size is equal to the number of images being selected @Tej I have updated the question

Comment: Post your moveFile() method as well.

Comment: done @ChaitanyaAtkuri

Comment: why are you using `return destinationImage;` code?

Comment: to return the file being moved and pass it in `postExecute()` @Rahulrr2602

Comment: @Amelia You should not return the file inside a for loop. You have more than one file which has to be transferred. This may be the reason that the files are not being transferred. You should not return anything there as returning will not execute the for loop further and hence other files will not be transferred.

Comment: @Amelia That is the reason why only one image is being transferred because you are breaking the for loop at the first time only and hence the rest of the images are not being transferred.

Comment: yes return statement breaks the for loop but if i remove it , it throws a null pointer exception as the doinbackground method need to return something, so  how do I fix that @Rahulrr2602

Comment: @Amelia Will post an answer that will solve your issue. Please wait.

Comment: @Amelia Have posted an answer please try and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why only one image is being moved is that you are breaking the for loop at the first time it is being executed by using the return statement.

To solve that replace you AsyncTask with the following

```
 public class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

              for (String imagePath : selectedImages) {   //this is the second for loop which might be running only once  
                File sourceImage = new File(imagePath); //returns the image File from model class to
                // be// moved.

                File destinationImage = new File(al_images.get(id).getDirectoryPath() +
                        File.separator + sourceImage.getName());

                try {
                    moveFile(sourceImage, destinationImage, false);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

     private void moveFile(File file_Source, File file_Destination, boolean isCopy) throws IOException {
        FileChannel source = null;
        FileChannel destination = null;
        if (!file_Destination.exists()) {
            file_Destination.createNewFile();
        }

        try {
            source = new FileInputStream(file_Source).getChannel();
            destination = new FileOutputStream(file_Destination).getChannel();

            long count = 0;
            long size = source.size();
            while ((count += destination.transferFrom(source, count, size - count)) < size) ;
            if (!isCopy) {
                file_Source.delete();
                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                        new String[] { file_Source.toString() }, null,null);
            }
        } finally {
            if (source != null) {
                source.close();
            }
            if (destination != null) {
                destination.close();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: why haven't you updated the view after moving the images ?

Comment: @Amelia Can you tell me which line is number 315.

Comment: `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,`

Comment: @Amelia OK. Try replacing `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this` with `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(YourActivity.this`. Also check if the source file is null or not.

Comment: Done that, and source file isn't null, otherwise it wouldn't have worked with previous code snippet too, I think

Comment: @Amelia Are you still getting that error? Also, is it crashing in the first file only?

Comment: @Amelia I am not pretty sure why the error is occurring but can you please try my updated code and also can you check if the ode is working fine without the media scanning code?

Comment: @Amelia If it is working fine without the Media Scanning code that the error has got to do something with scanning then we will have to figure out the exact reason for it.

Comment: @Amelia also can you show me this method or code `destination.transferFrom`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163554/discussion-between-rahulrr2602-and-amelia).